# Redirecting URL to correct title by ID

Tags: html, url, redirect

Websites retrieve an article merely by ID and the rest of url is not important at all. For example, all of these versions work

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854223/redirecting-url-to-correct-title-by-id
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854223/SOMETHING_ELSE
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854223/
```

But well-developed websites like StackExchange will redirect any incorrect title (lines 2 and 3 of above list) to the original link structure (i.e. line 1).

How this process is conducted?

The basic idea is to simply redirect all requests to the corrected structure; then, this needs loading the page two times. However, this process is very fast and should be conducted with another method.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is using a 301 Moved Permanently redirect to achieve this. Use a [Redirect Checker](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/) to see this.